# Lenovo L560 cant join company wlan

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, lenovo-laptop

We have the same wlan shared in two different sites, completely normal corporation situation, same SSID and so on. One client joins very well to wlan on site where also wlan-controller is. But when he goes to other site what is behind the mpls-cloud, he can't join company-wlan. 
Error it says is "cant connect to wlan" (or something like that, not sure what it is in English) when pressing connect.

I have updated wlan-drivers on that computer. Also I noticed I can't join with any account on that computer to that wlan.

Answer (score 0):

I succeeded to get it work last week, and I should had to do it earlier already but yeah.

Problem were solved by restarting only AP in that site. I dont really know what was wrong in it, but atleast corporate wlan started to work. (Note, before restarting it seemed to be working just correct by stats and led).